# What's the ways of prevention and treatment of arithmetic overflow in C#?

Tags: c#

What's the ways of prevention and treatment of arithmetic overflow in C#?

And Conversion an arithmetic overflow (logical error) to a runtime error?

I want at least 3 ways for solve this prob!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use checked.

```
int z = 0;
    try
    {
        // The following line raises an exception because it is checked.
        z = checked(maxIntValue + 10);
    }
    catch (System.OverflowException e)
    {
        // The following line displays information about the error.
        Console.WriteLine("CHECKED and CAUGHT:  " + e.ToString());
    }
    // The value of z is still 0. 
    return z;
```

see the example and explanation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw.aspx

More ways of doing this as requested by OP:

You can also use `Int32.MaxValue` (for int arithmetic) to check if an operation might cause overflow, then either throw your own exception or `System.OverflowException`

Something like `if ((Int32.MaxValue - x) < y) throw new Exception()`

Comment: I really wish `checked` got more lip service. It's a phenomenal feature.

Comment: I need more ways. checked is usefull but it's not enough.

Comment: @NasimVakili *Could you be any more vague?!* What else are you looking for exactly? This is **the** correct answer, why do you need others? Is this for homework?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart :) yes i'm new in programming and also C# and searched about it and find checked and GetHashCode method but i need any ways to solve or prevent this like round the prob. and yes it's a homework.

Comment: @3dd: `if((x+y) > Int32.MaxValue)` would still throw an `OverflowException` because you have to *be able* to add `x+y` to make the comparison. Perhaps `if ((Int32.MaxValue - x) < y)` instead?

Comment: @DanPuzey ah good point, I'll update my ans, thanx

Comment: @NasimVakili: `GetHashCode` method has nothing to do with this problem. The only sensible answer to the question is the one 3dd has posted. (And this still doesn't *solve* the problem, just detects it: you still can't actually add the numbers.)